# Execute Dynamic Stored Procedure in another Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a dynamic stored procedure that I run in Access 2013 by passing various parameters to it.

However, I need to now run the dynamic stored procedure in another Stored Procedure.
Currently I know how to Execute a standard stored procedure.

This is my dynamic stored procedure Execute that I use in another SP Called **SP_ACTIVITY**:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@ORGCODE VARCHAR(6), @COMPANYID VARCHAR(6)' 
                              @ORGCODE, @COMPANYID;
```

Here is my code so far:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ASP_SLACTIVITYPAGE]
 @ORGCODE2 AS VARCHAR(6),
@COMPANYID2 AS VARCHAR(6)

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON; 


 IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tempdb..sysobjects 
WHERE NAME = '#TempACTIVITY' and TYPE = 'U')

DROP TABLE #TempACTIVITY

 CREATE TABLE #tempACTIVITY
        (
        CompanyID VARCHAR(6),
        CompanyName VARCHAR(50),
        PostingID INT,
        EntryDate SmallDateTime,
        TransType VARCHAR(2),
        Ref VARCHAR(50),
        Nominal INT,
        Details VARCHAR(50),
        SumofNetAmt DECIMAL(12,2),
        SumofVATAmt DECIMAL(12,2),
        SumofPaidAmt DECIMAL(12,2),
        CustomerOrderNr VARCHAR(25),
        WONUmber INT,
        PaidStatus VARCHAR(2),
        Credit DECIMAL(12,2),
        Debit DECIMAL(12,2),
        OutStanding DECIMAL(12,2)
        );
 GO     

    INSERT INTO #tempACTIVITY
        (
        CompanyID,
        CompanyName,
        PostingID,
        EntryDate,
        TransType,
        Ref,
        Nominal,
        Details,
        SumofNetAmt,
        SumofVATAmt,
        SumofPaidAmt,
        CustomerOrderNr,
        WONUmber,
        PaidStatus,
        Credit,
        Debit,
        OutStanding
        )
    EXEC sp_executesql SP_ACTVIITY, @ORGCODE2, @COMPANYID2 <---- 
 ---I want to execute with dynamic SP with parameters like the the one above.
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Do you want to execute the above code in a stored procedure?

Comment: My question is I want to execute the dynamic query in the procedure above

Comment: @NickyvV I'm just not sure what the syntax is for quoting in another dynamic stored procedure with parameters. have you tried this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was quoting the Stored Procedure incorrectly.

The answer is:

```
EXEC [PROCNAME] @Param1, @Param2
```